# Каким образом вы бы это реализовали

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Есть в макете такой элемент. Однако я уже второй день ломаю голову и никак не могу придумать как такое можно релизовать, работая с бутстрапом. В этом, собственно и суть вопроса.

[image: heads will roll]

Comment: Хоть строчу кода за 2 дня написали? Предъявите. )

Comment: Нет, линию сзади них. Пробовал просто нарисовать линию и наложить кружки поверх них, но получается просто вакханалия при адаптации.

Comment: Покажите что Вы пробовали. С нуля тут многие нарисовать это могут.

Comment: @Данил ну дак надо в относительных единицах задавать размеры линии.

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}
ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #C5FCC5;
  z-index: -1;
}
ul > li {
  margin: 15px 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: #C5FCC5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
}
ul > li:first-child {
  background: #6CEE5A;
}
ul > li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #91E0E5;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
ul > li:last-of-type:before {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul > li:before {   
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>2016</li>
  <li>2015</li>
  <li>2014</li>
  <li>2013</li>
  <li>2012</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А палочки вертикальные где?

Comment: @Other, в фотошопе

Comment: @Grundy, там тоньше.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cell{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border-left: 1px solid cyan;
  border-right: 1px solid cyan;
  position: relative;

}
.wrapper{
  float:left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.cell > span{
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.7em);
  left: calc(50% - 1.1em);
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.cell > svg{
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  fill: hsl(120, 80%, 90%);
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  padding: 1px;
  --opacity: 0.4;
}
.wrapper:hover > .cell > svg {
  fill: lightgreen;
}
.super-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.super-wrapper:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(120, 80%, 90%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='super-wrapper'>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='cell'>
    <span>2016</span>
    <svg>
      <circle cx='20' cy='20' r='20'/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='cell'>
    <span>2015</span>
    <svg>
      <circle cx='20' cy='20' r='20'/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='cell'>
    <span>2014</span>
    <svg>
      <circle cx='20' cy='20' r='20'/>
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Кодить палку в центре было влом нормально, да и рабочий день к концу идет, так что, влепил костыль, коли надо будет, доделаете :^)

Коли нет, сам допилю завтра.